# Set Up I2C Address Without Device Attached

Tags: linux, embedded, i2c

I've been trying to learn about I2C today, it's taken me some time to set up but I've now got a Raspberry Pi configured with `i2c-tools` installed and I can see `/dev/i2c-0`.

However when I run `i2cdetect -y 0` I get an empty address table. This makes sense as I don't have any device connected to the I2C bus. What I would like to do is be able to write to the I2C pins and observe the output using my oscilloscope or even connect an LED so I can see state changes.

Is this even possible, and if so how would I go about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided you have everything set up correctly, you should see something on your scope while i2cdetect scans the I2C bus for available devices.

I2C is built such that you get a NACK after writing the i2c-address if you try to talk to an address that doesn't exist on the bus. This is how i2cdetect knows a device of a specific address doesn't exist on the bus. So you can't see any actual data transactions without having another device on the bus. [See the  I2C User Manual.](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10204.pdf)

I suggest you attach a simple I2C device such as an RTC (like DS3231M or DS3232M) or a temperature sensor on your I2C bus and try interfacing with them to see an actual I2C transaction.

Another method (which I usually use) is to have another microcontroller with a known-good I2C-slave implementation act as a loopback on the bus.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. As I don't have any I2C devices to hand I will try your loopback suggestion.

Comment: I'd also suggest making sure you have pullups on the I2C lines.

Comment: @Akhil how can i write to particular  i2c device using its address to check whether its connected or not?

Comment: @Mr.32 If you're using linux, try using i2get and i2cset programs that are also part of i2c-tools along with i2cdetect.

Comment: @Akhil i want to do in linux kernel code...is there any func for that?